# Can't find type option in product attribute?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add M L XL size with different stock quantity. I tried to add SIZE attribute on a product page under. Please see the image[image]

Then it looks like this

[image: This is variation]

I'm using all latest version of WordPress, WpBackery Page and WooCommerce.
I'm trying to add 3 sizes for a single page with different stock quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think when you click "SIZE" in your image one, there is an **option** should be **ticked** and the **attribute options** should be selected too: **used for variations** 
and **Select All**(**this may be slightly varied due to different plugins**) :

The following is how I add the variations to the product, for all those who couldn't find the variations editing:
1 Add the attributes under product tab:
[image]

2 Edit the attribute :
[image]

3 Go to product page and in **product-data** choose **variable product**, and if you have variations for one attribute, the option needs to be ticked, and **the options should also be selected**,read the next 3 images and **select the options**: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

4 Now go to **variation** tab:
[image]

[image]

Hope this can help, any questions please leave comments :)